# How to mock com.google.inject.Binder and org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

According to my requirement I have to increase my code coverage to 80% I some how reached up to 71% but 30% of code is written in main class and the YAML config loader class. Can anyone tell me how to write test cases for following methods:-

```
private String configFilePath;

    private Optional<ItemMasterFileProcessorConfiguration> config;

    public ItemMasterFileProcessorTaskModule(String configFilePath)
    {
        this.configFilePath = configFilePath;
        config = Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Binder binder)
    {
        binder.bind(<Interface>.class).to(<ImplClass>.class);
        binder.bind(<Interface>.class).to(<ImplClass>.class);
    }

    @Provides
    public ItemMasterFileProcessorConfiguration getConfig() throws ItemMasterFileProcessorException
    {
        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();

        try
        {
            if (!config.isPresent())
            {
                ItemMasterFileProcessorConfiguration writerConfig = yaml.loadAs(ItemMasterFileProcessorConfiguration.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configFilePath), ItemMasterFileProcessorConfiguration.class);
                config = Optional.of(writerConfig);
            }
            /*
             * Sonar is wanting is to add isPresent() before this But if I do
             * Sonar complains that it will always evaluate to TRUE
             */
            return config.get();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new ItemMasterFileProcessorException("Config is NULL while initializing configuration for config path : {}", e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a temp file with valid config I don't see any issues in testing your class. You can use `TemporaryFolder` from JUnit to create temp files and some IOUtils to write config in yaml format into the file.

The following example is from official `org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder` javadoc

```
 public static class HasTempFolder {
  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder folder= new TemporaryFolder();

  @Test
  public void testUsingTempFolder() throws IOException {
      File createdFile= folder.newFile("myfile.txt");
      File createdFolder= folder.newFolder("subfolder");
      // ...
     }
 }
```